# Android:Passing a hash map between Activities

Tags: android, dictionary, android-activity, android-intent

I have a map between string and a class object. I populate this map in Activity1 and i would like to pass it to activity2.

```
public class NEW extends Activity {

    public class data {
            String name;
            float value;
                 ....   etc  }

 ......   
    static Map<String, data> data_map = new HashMap<String, data>();
   .....  }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I am assuming you own both Activities (call them A and B). In which case just put the map in a public static variable and access it from B via A.data_map.

*[update]*

For all of the downvotes take a peek at the [Android Application Framework FAQ](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html) section "How do I pass data between Activities/Services within a single application?". The solution I recommend is exactly the same as...

> **A public static field/method**
>
> An alternate way to make data
>   accessible across Activities/Services
>   is to **use public static fields** and/or
>   methods. You can access these static
>   fields from any other class in your
>   application. To share an object, the
>   activity which creates your object
>   sets a static field to point to this
>   object and any other activity that
>   wants to use this object just accesses
>   this static field.

Yes, there are caveats to this solution but with the limited info presented by the OP we can not assume this method will not work.

Comment: No that is broken.  For example, if the user leaves your app, it gets killed in the background, and they return, then when activity B is instantiated it will now found that data_map is null.

Comment: Thank You Andrew ! It works ! I was thinking in terms of bundles and intents.

Comment: @hackbod: Not broken at all; B should just have the proper logic in place to preserve state during onPause.

Comment: This is broken.  Seriously.  Saving that state requires you do the EXACT SAME THING as you'd need to propagate the state across to the new activity.

Comment: @hackbod: depends on what he is doing with the map; I've use this method a lot and I've never had any problems.

Comment: Sooner or later you will have problems.  All you need to do is go home, kill your process, and then return to your app.  Your top activity is re-created but your global is now reset to empty.

Comment: @Andrew White its exactly true what hackbod says. It will broken and data in the arraylist are cleared.its gives size as 0 for arraylist.

Comment: According to the question this solution is right. It didn't said anywhere that the data needs to be persisted... just shared between the activities.  Of course there are other solutions like sharing it via a Bundle (making a Parceable class) but it involves unnecessary coding if you just want to share the data.

Answer (score 54):

The best way to do this is if you can express your data in the primitives supported by Bundle, so it can be placed in the Intent you are sending through the Intent.putExtra() methods.  (EXCEPT for the use of Serializable, which is extremely slow and inefficient.)

However you can't do this because (a) you are using a Map and (b) your map contains a custom data type.

The formally correct solution to this exact problem is to write a custom Parcellable class that takes care of marshalling/unmarshalling your data structure.  I'll sketch out the code here, though it may not be exactly correct:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.os.Parcelable.Creator;

public class MyData implements Parcelable {
    HashMap<String, data> data_map = new HashMap<String, data>();

    public MyData() {
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int parcelableFlags) {
        final int N = data_map.size();
        dest.writeInt(N);
        if (N > 0) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, data> entry : data_map.entrySet()) {
                dest.writeString(entry.getKey());
                data dat = entry.getValue();
                dest.writeString(dat.name);
                dest.writeFloat(dat.value);
                // etc...
            }
        }
    }

    public static final Creator<MyData> CREATOR = new Creator<MyData>() {
        public MyData createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new MyData(source);
        }
        public MyData[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyData[size];
        }
    };

    private MyData(Parcel source) {
        final int N = source.readInt();
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            String key = source.readString();
            data dat = new data();
            dat.name = source.readString();
            dat.value = source.readFloat();
            // etc...
            data_map.put(key, dat);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that when you have a custom data structure like your "data" class, it can be cleaner to also make that Parcellable, so it knows how to read/write its contents in a Parcel, and the code here would just call .writeToParcel(...) and a .readFromParcel(...) method on it instead of knowing the details of its contents.  That way when you add new fields to "data" you don't forget to also update this other marshalling code to know about them.

Comment: @hckbod: "Serializable, which is extremely slow and inefficient" do you have a source for this; I've never seen any performance issue with it.

Comment: I have measured it in the past.  It is slow.  Especially compared to Parcelable.  Trust me.

Comment: @hackbod: without some sort of source, document, or proof I'm not much to just take someone's word at it. Since the serializer can represent arbitrary objects and most mobile data is "small" I have a hard time recommending against it.

Comment: @Andrew: Read hackbod's profile to see why you can take her word for it ;)

Comment: @Andrew: Yes indeed, the about box could indeed be a fabrication. But then someone should inform Dianne Hackborn that she has an impostor who, for some reason, has authored an impressive number of in-depth posts about Android on StackOverflow. :)

Comment: Some benchmarks would be nice (@Andrew, perhaps you'd take that task for us?) No disrespect to Dianne - I have always been curious to see metrics.  Intuition would say that serializing / deserializing is going to have obvious performance implications.

Comment: @AndrewWhite Serializable uses reflection which is slow.  Parcellable takes more work to implement because it doesn't use reflection but it does make it faster.  Hackbod, just because it's slower doesn't make it wrong.  Premature optimization is also bad.  If you can have lightweight code with Serializeable that doesn't create bottlenecks, you're in a great place

Comment: See the speed tests at the bottom of this post - http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using Intents, which work for both static and arbitary objects (as long as they implement Serializable). Create a custom [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for your application and then pass on your HashMap (not a Map, which doesn't implement Serializable!) as extra data:

```
Intent act2 = new Intent(Activity2.SHOW_ME);
act2.putExtra("data", data_map);
```

Then in Activity2, you can call `getIntent()` and check via `Intent.getAction().equals(Activity2.SHOW_ME)` whether you were the one calling your Activity. If so, you can access your extra data by

```
Intent caller = getIntent();
if (caller.getAction().equals(Activity2.SHOW_ME)) {
   Map<String, NEW.data> data_map = (Map<String, NEW.data>)caller.getExtras().get("data");
}
```

Hope I typed everything correctly ;) This assumes, that your Intent action-string is stored as `static final string SHOW_ME = "yourpackage.yourname";` in Activity2.

If you need further clarification, add a comment.

Comment: I tried some thing like ,                                           Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.MYPACKAGE.MYCLASS2");                 intent.putExtra("data",data_map);                                              But Getting error message as "The method putExtra is not applicable for the arguments"

Comment: Yes i have them. I checked without passing the data, i'm able to navigate to the second activity.(like second page) but i'm getting compilation error if i try  intent.putExtra("data",data_map);  As putExtra doesnt take map.

Comment: Ah sorry, yes, this is because Map doesn't implement Serializable. You must change your `data_map` type to `HashMap<String, data>`.

Comment: I strongly suggest not using Serializable, it is extremely slow.

Comment: Well I don't have any experiences with this, but if he wants to use a HashMap, it implements it by default. Answer 2 below would be another option.

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate your data in a Bound Service as described in this document:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html

Don't forget to add your server to the manifest file.

this solution has the advantage of decoupling your data from your UI, which will ultimately lead to a more maintainable design.

If the need arrises you can add a messaging wrapper to your service's API to allow it to be called from other processes / applications

Answer (score -3):

Create a new java file which will be global for whole application.

**Step1**:

```
public class GlobalClass extends android.app.Application 
{
 public static Map<String, NEW.data> data_map = new Map<String, NEW.data>();
}
```

**Step2**:

After doing that, Register this "GlobalClass" in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:name=".GlobalClass"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</application>
```

**Step3**:

now you can use this Map anywhere in your application.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
 GlobalClass global = (GlobalClass)getApplication();
 Map<String, NEW.data> my_map_data = global.data_map;
}
```

These steps maybe helpful for you...

Comment: A big no for storing data in Application class. When apps goes to background, and if system kills your app,
application class will create a new instance, instead of the original instance, then the data will be lost. (You may try it for limiting background process in developer options)