# Passing Arraylist between activities? Using Parcelable

Tags: java, android

**EDIT:** I've updated my question considerably and am now going with Parcelable as my method.

I'm attempting to a pass an ArrayList from one activity to another. I've been reading around and can't seem to find any answers to my problem.

I've got an `ArrayList<SearchList>` which `implements Parcelable` SearchList has the following code...

```
  public class SearchList implements Parcelable {
private String title;
  private String description;
  private String link;
  public SearchList(String name, String phone, String mail) {
          super();
          this.title = name;
          this.description = phone;
          this.link = mail;
  }
  public SearchList(Parcel source){
      /*
       * Reconstruct from the Parcel
       */
      title = source.readString();
      description = source.readString();
      link = source.readString();
}
  public String gettitle() {
          return title;
  }
  public void setTitle(String title) {
          this.title = title;
  }
  public String getDescription() {
          return description;
  }
  public void setDescription(String description) {
          this.description = description;
  }
  public String getLink() {
          return link;
  }
  public void setLink(String link) {
          this.link = link;
  }

public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
      dest.writeString(title);
      dest.writeString(description);
      dest.writeString(link);

}

 public static final Creator<SearchList> CREATOR = new Creator<SearchList>() {
        public SearchList createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new SearchList(source);
        }
        public SearchList[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SearchList[size];
        }
    };
  }
```

However, when I try and do...

```
 List<SearchList> listOfResults = new ArrayList<SearchList>();
 intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("results", listOfResults);
```

I get `not applicable for type (String, List<SearchList>` why?

Comment: A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566921/androidpassing-a-hash-map-between-activities/). Hopefully it can help you!

Comment: This tutorial should help you implement the parcelable interface: http://www.anddev.org/simple_tutorial_passing_arraylist_across_activities-t9996.html

Answer (score 1):

Could you use all String values, and change from `bundle.putSerializable()` to `bundle.putStringArrayList("key", ArrayList<String>_object)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite as alternative. To pass data from one Activity to another. Here the [link](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742).

Comment: What's performance like for this?