# Android: getParcelable returning null?

Tags: java, android, parcelable

As a follow on from my last question: [Passing Arraylist between activities? Using Parcelable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636806/passing-arraylist-between-activities-using-parcelable)

I'm now attempting to pass my ArrayList via Parcelable. However, when it's gotten from the other activity it returns null. I can't seem to figure out why. I've got the following...

ResultsList.java

```
 public class ResultsList extends ArrayList<SearchList> implements Parcelable {

    /**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -78190146280643L;

 public ResultsList(){

}

public ResultsList(Parcel in){
    readFromParcel(in);
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public ResultsList createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ResultsList(in);
    }

    public Object[] newArray(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

};

private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    this.clear();

    //First we have to read the list size
    int size = in.readInt();

    //Reading remember that we wrote first the Name and later the Phone Number.
    //Order is fundamental

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        String title = in.readString();
        String Des = in.readString();
        String message = in.readString();
        SearchList c = new SearchList(title,Des,link);
        this.add(c);
    }

}

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    int size = this.size();
    //We have to write the list size, we need him recreating the list
    dest.writeInt(size);
    //We decided arbitrarily to write first the Name and later the Phone Number.
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        SearchList c = this.get(i);
        dest.writeString(c.gettitle());
        dest.writeString(c.getDescription());
        dest.writeString(c.getmessage());
    }
}
 }
```

SearchList.java

```
 public class SearchList {
private String title;
  private String description;
  private String message;
  public SearchList(String name, String phone, String mail) {
          super();
          this.title = name;
          this.description = phone;
          this.message = mail;
  }
  public String gettitle() {
          return title;
  }
  public void setTitle(String title) {
          this.title = title;
  }
  public String getDescription() {
          return description;
  }
  public void setDescription(String description) {
          this.description = description;
  }
  public String getmessage() {
          return message;
  }
  public void setmessage(String link) {
          this.message = message;
  }
 }
```

`listOfResults` is declared as `ResultsList listOfResults = new ResultsList();` and filled earlier in the code It's then sent with...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this ,newthing.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelable("results", listOfResults);
    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

Receiving...

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    ResultsList results = extras.getParcelable("results");
```

I'd like to point out I'm testing this null thing by checking the size() of the Arraylist going into the Bundle and then it coming out. It goes in fine and comes out null.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't attach bundle to intent! (doh!)  was pointed out by a kind gent on IRC! #android-dev