# Pass ArrayList between two activities using Parcelable and Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist, parcelable

At the moment I have the problem to pass an `ArrayList<MyClass>` from one activity to another. I tried to implement Parcelable in MyClass and use an intent in the activity but it seems that I did something wrong. When I call `startActivity` with the `intent` the window of the app freezes and I get the Error "!!! Failed Bender Transaction !!!". I've read here and on some other places that the size of the transaction may cause the error. MyClass holds one Image. In the moment `startActivity` is called the `ArrayList` holds five elements with one bitmap for each element. The size of all images together is below 70kb.

Here is my actual code:

```
public class MyClass implements Parcelable {

public enum Type {
    VIDEO, AUDIO
}

private int id;
private String name;
private String url;
private double longitude;
private double latitude;
private double gpsDistance;
private String description;
private String thumb;
private Bitmap thumbpic;
private Type type;

public MyClass() {
    this.gpsDistance = 0;
}

public MyClass(Parcel in) {
    readFromParcel(in);
}

/* Setter & Getter */


public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(url);
    dest.writeDouble(longitude);
    dest.writeDouble(latitude);
    dest.writeDouble(gpsDistance);
    dest.writeString(description);
    dest.writeString(thumb);
    dest.writeParcelable(thumbpic, flags);
    dest.writeString((type == null) ? "" : type.name());

}



private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    this.id = in.readInt();
    this.name = in.readString();
    this.url = in.readString();
    this.longitude = in.readDouble();
    this.latitude = in.readDouble();
    this.gpsDistance = in.readDouble();
    this.description = in.readString();
    this.thumb = in.readString();
    this.thumbpic = (Bitmap) in.readParcelable(getClass().getClassLoader());
    try {
        type = Type.valueOf(in.readString());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException x) {
        type = null;
    }
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public MyClass createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new MyClass(in);
    }

    public MyClass[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MyClass[size];
    }
};
}
```

Some code snippets from the activity (`MainActivity`) which starts the second one (`ListActivity`)

```
ArrayList<Content> contentElements  = new ArrayList<Content>();

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListActivity.class);

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("content", contentElements);
```

The handling in the `ListActivity`

```
Intent i = getIntent();
contentElements= i.getParcelableArrayListExtra("content");
```

Does someone have an idea what caused this problem and have solution or an alternative approach?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Arraylist between activities? Using Parcelable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636806/passing-arraylist-between-activities-using-parcelable)

Comment: This problem is solved now. The size of the bitmaps was too high to use an intent. To deal with it I save them into the FileDir and MyClass holds the URI instead of the real bitmap.