# Can someone describe with simple and detailed example how to use parcelable in tranfer objects etc to other activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

i am new to android and i am working on understanding the concept of parcelable used to transfer objects and complex data from one activity to other. But i am unable to understand how to use it and how to implement it in activity classes. Can someone please help me to understand this concept in detail and in simple way?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) is useful code snippet for class, that should implement `Parcelable` interface.

Using such objects is simple enough. Add extra for intent: `Intent.putExtra(String name, Parcelable value)`, use this intent to start activity. In `onCreate` just read it: `getIntent().getParcelableExtra(String)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar question: [Android:Passing a hash map between Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566921/androidpassing-a-hash-map-between-activities/)

take a look at hackbod's answer.. it explains what you have to do