# Android Passing hashtable from two activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, hashtable

I want to pass this structure from intent A to intent B:
Hashtable> parsedData;

I do this:
//intent A

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this,B.class);
intent.putExtra("placemarkOnMap", placemarkOnMap);`
```

//intent B

```
Serializable data = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("placemarkOnMap"); 
placemarkOnMap = new Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String,String>> ((Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String,String>>)data);
```

This return placemarkOnMap = {} but placemarkOnMap is not empty in the activity A.

What is wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566921/androidpassing-a-hash-map-between-activities

Comment: That questions indicates how to pass objects between activities via static fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a new Hashtable and initialize it with the one you get from the intent. This:

```
  placemarkOnMap = new Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String,String>> ((Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String,String>>)data);
```

can be replaced with :

```
placemarkOnMap = (Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String,String>>)data;
```

Other than that, make sure your Hashtable has values in it right before you put it in the intent. Since somethin gets deserializd for the "placemarkOnMap" that means you've put something there, but it was empty.

Comment: I have this exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap

Comment: My hashtable has values in Activity A

Comment: @michele Are you sure placemarkOnMap is not HashMap but a Hashtable?

Comment: yes this is the declaration:

 private Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String,String>> placemarkOnMap = new Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String,String>>();