# Bundle HashMap with custom object

Tags: java, android, hashmap, bundle

I have a problem about Bundle `HashMap` in `onSaveInstanceState()` in `SupportMapFragment`.

The logcat message is following:

> E/AndroidRuntime(12445): android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.myapp.model.StationHashMap

Already try some solutions :

1. In `onSaveInstanceState()`, add `bundle.setClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());`
2. In `onSaveInstanceState()`, use `bundle.putSerializable(SAVE_INSTANCE_KEY_SATION_MAP, mStationMap);` directly put **HashMap** in bundle, but the logcat message change into **com.myapp.model.Station**.

Following code:

- **MapFragment.java**: extends `SupportMapFragment`, I want in `onSaveInstanceState()` save the previous state data
- **StationHashMap.java**: store HashMap, implements `Parcelable`
- **Station.java**: store all Station data, also implements `Parcelable`

**MapFragment.java**

```
  private HashMap<String, Station> mStationMap;
  ...

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    StationHashMap stationHashMap = new StationHashMap();
    stationHashMap.setStationMap(mStationMap);

    outState.putParcelable(SAVE_INSTANCE_KEY_SATION_MAP, stationHashMap);
  }
```

The way in **StationHashMap.java** is reference from: [question]: [Android:Passing a hash map between Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566921/androidpassing-a-hash-map-between-activities/5567917#5567917)

**StationHashMap.java**

```
public class StationHashMap implements Parcelable {
    private HashMap<String, Station> mStationMap = new HashMap<String, Station>();

    public StationHashMap() {
    }

    public void setStationMap(HashMap<String, Station> stationMap) {
        mStationMap = stationMap;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Station> getStationMap() {
        return mStationMap;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        Log.d(this.toString(), "in writeToParcel()");

        final int mapSize = mStationMap.size();

        dest.writeInt(mapSize);

        if (mapSize > 0) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, Station> entry : mStationMap.entrySet()) {
                dest.writeString(entry.getKey());

                Station station = entry.getValue();

                dest.writeInt(station.getId());
                dest.writeInt(station.getNo());
                dest.writeString(station.getName());
                dest.writeString(station.getAddress());
                dest.writeDouble(station.getLat());
                dest.writeDouble(station.getLng());
                dest.writeString(station.getDesc());
                dest.writeInt(station.getBikeNum());
                dest.writeInt(station.getEmptyNum());
            }
        }

    }

    public static final Creator<StationHashMap> CREATOR = new Creator<StationHashMap>() {

        @Override
        public StationHashMap createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new StationHashMap(source);
        }

        @Override
        public StationHashMap[] newArray(int size) {
            return new StationHashMap[size];
        }

    };

    private StationHashMap(Parcel source) {
        Log.d(this.toString(), "in StationHashMap()");

        final int mapSize = source.readInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < mapSize; i++) {
            String key = source.readString();
            Station station = new Station();

            station.setId(source.readInt());
            station.setNo(source.readInt());
            station.setName(source.readString());
            station.setAddress(source.readString());
            station.setLat(source.readDouble());
            station.setLng(source.readDouble());
            station.setDesc(source.readString());
            station.setBikeNum(source.readInt());
            station.setEmptyNum(source.readInt());

            mStationMap.put(key, station);
        }
    }
}
```

**Station.java**

```
public class Station implements Parcelable {
    private int mId;
    private int mNo;
    private String mName;

    public Station() {

    }

  // getters and setters...

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        mId = in.readInt();
        mNo = in.readInt();
        mName = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(mId);
        dest.writeInt(mNo);
    }

    private Station(Parcel in) {
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Station> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Station>() {

        @Override
        public Station createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Station(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Station[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Station[size];
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: I have the same problem right now. Looks like the only option which i didnt try yet was to save the state using the Arguments of the Fragment. But thats really a bad practice

Comment: I used the above method to practice.