# How to pass collection between Activities in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

**what i am trying to do**::

- I am trying to pass a collection from one activity to another and display the received collection in a Log
- I am aware that this can be achieved using intents so i am using them

**What i am not able to do**::

- How to receive the `hashmap` in the `Screen1.java` display it in a Log

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    HashMap<String, String> objColl;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        objColl=new HashMap<String, String>();
        objColl.put("1", "USA");
        objColl.put("2", "Canada");
        objColl.put("3", "Africa");
        objColl.put("4", "England");

        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.button1:
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Screen1.class);
            intent.putExtra("key1", objColl);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }   
    }
}
```

**Screen1.java**

```
public class Screen1 extends Activity {

    HashMap<String, String> objColl;
    TextView txtVw;
    String res;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        txtVw=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();

    }
}
```

---

**Log**::

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android:Passing a hash map between Activities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566921/androidpassing-a-hash-map-between-activities)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sender Activity:**

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap= ....
Intent intent = new Intent(SourceActivity.this, DestinationActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("hashMap", hashMap);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Receiver Activity:**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();    
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) intent.getSerializableExtra("hashMap");
```

Answer (score 1):

Get Extras you need to use Bundle

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        if(mIntent != null){
            Bundle mBudle = mIntent.getExtras();
            HashMap<String, String> mMap = (HashMap<String, String>) mBudle.get("key1");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass collection to intent using bundle-

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putSerializable("HashMap",Hash_Map);
intent.putExtras(extras);
```

& in other activity-

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
 if(bundle!=null){
   Hash_Map= bundle.getSerializable("HashMap");
```