# How to use Parcelable with HashMap

Tags: android, parcelable, serializable

I am solving problem with **HashMap**. I have to pass data from one fragment to another using Parcelable. How can I achieve this?

Comment: use Bundle ... it is kind of map

Comment: Are looking for how to make a HashMap  Parcelable?!

Comment: You can follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566921/androidpassing-a-hash-map-between-activities) to get your answer.

Comment: @Selvin you realize that `HashMap` has to be passed as a `Parcelable` into a `Bundle`... You're not only rude, but also wrong.

Comment: @tolgap you realize that Bundle has almost the same interface and it is Parcelable  so it can used instead ... you are so wrong

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to use a wrapper class, or maybe just commit a datamodel to the HashMap so you can have a `List<ObjectToReplaceHashMap>` which you can send with `putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value)` and `getParcelableArray(String key)`

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5567917/4623782 for more information